# Append index variable at the end of each line

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am trying to append an index variable at the end of each line of a file that I have. However I dont want to lose the escape characters that I have in the textFile and thus cannot echo into the file again.

Here's what I tried:

```
while read p; do               
                tempCom+=$p
                tempCom+=$indexVar
                echo $tempCom >> otherFile.txt               
                tempCom=""
done < result.txt
```

What I am after:

```
Read:
"asdasdasdasdasdasd\ asdasd/asda"
"qweqweqweqweqweqwe\ qweqwe/qweq"

Output:
"asdasdasdasdasdasd\ asdasd/asda" 1
"qweqweqweqweqweqwe\ qweqwe/qweq" 2
```

Note that indexVar is an index that is stored elsewhere and does not necessarily correspond to the line that its being appended to.

Comment: Could you possibly show a small sample of the indexVar file?

Comment: @G-- Its simply a number thats pulled into the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-r` option of the `read` command, so that the backslashes are preserved.

```
while read -r p; do
```

Comment: @mixkat you accepted this answer, fine, but make sure you use the advices found in mine: use `IFS= ` and quote the expansion of `tempCom`.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is very likely a quoting problem. Observe the `IFS=` and the `-r` option in the `read` statement too.

```
while IFS= read -r p
    tempCom+=$p$indexVar
    printf '%s\n' "$tempCom" >> otherFile.txt # Observe the quotes
    tempCom=
done < result.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to append the line number to the end why not use `awk`?

```
awk '{print $0, "\t", NR}' < file.txt
```

EDIT 1: It sounds like you want to use [paste](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/paste/) then (assuming you want to just join line by line)

```
paste file1.txt file2.txt > fileresults.txt
```

EDIT 2: You can use sed then:

```
sed "s|$|${indexVar}|" input
```

Comment: Sorry I edited the post I should have said that already but the index doesnot correspond to the line numbers.

Comment: Your `sed` solution works provided `indexVar` never changes throughout the file and doesn't contain `|` symbols.

Comment: I'm not really sure how `indexVar` is being set/changed.

Comment: Indexvar could change so the sed option is not viable. The -r flag did it tho. thanks.